# AWS - print out lambda's payload result

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, aws-lambda

My Lambda call uses `--payload` param to to run another cli command. How to print cli's payload result in Lambda's log?

Currently I'm getting simple `{"status":"OK"}`

```
set -x 
 ls
 aws sts get-caller-identity 
 aws lambda invoke \
    --function-name my_func \
    --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out \
    --payload '{"command":"/opt/awscli/aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message '$1' --output text"}' \
    --output text \
    response.json
```

Comment: Well you'd have to configure the lambda function to return that in the output payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding final line in above script did the trick:

```
cat response.json
```